# Seeking advice to create my own Quran database

Tags: mysql, database-design

[The Quran Database site](http://www.qurandatabase.org/) has The Holy Quran in various languages (and various translations within that language) in various database formats. (Each translation is a separate database file in various formats.)

The format is:

```
| ID | DatabaseID | ChapterID | VerseID | VerseText                                             |
|----|------------|-----------|---------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 100        | 1         | 1       | In the name of Allah, most benevolent, ever-merciful. |
| 2  | 100        | 1         | 2       | All Praise belongs to Allah, Lord of all the worlds,  |
```

I am seeking advice to start on the right foot with respect to:

1. I want to construct a database where I can see all the translations (that I am interested in and have downloaded). I would think the simple method would be to import each translation in a separate table under the same database. Do I need to think anything else?
2. For my studies, I need to be able to assign tags to the verses (many-to-many relationship: a verse may have multiple tags, a tag may have multiple verses) (this I think I can figure out how) and also assign many-to-many symmetric relations between the verses. [I have come across this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3550093/1085805) but I am still confused as to what the best practice is. Example:

> ```
> | ID | ID  |
> |----|-----|
> | 1  | 85  |
> | 1  | 116 |
> | 1  | 985 |
> | 2  | 96  |
> | .. | ..  |
> ```

(Here, the `ID` represents the row ID)

Thus when I query a certain verse, I should be able to (if I want to) see what other verses are related to that verse.

Here is a further problem I have no idea as to how to properly implement: Suppose that Chapter X Verse Y, Y+1, Y+2 is related to Chapter W Verse Z (so Y, Y+1, Y+2 is related as a whole). How does that affect my choice to implement symmetrical relation design?

(I plan to work with MySQL.)

Comment: Strongly suggest studying up on entity relationships. 1-1, 1-Many, Many-Many. Hint: Pick out the nouns in what you posted and consider the relationships between them...ex, Quran_English and Labels... One verse could have many labels, one label could be used in many verses, so perhaps create a table Quran_Labels to relate them... Do this for all your entity relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, do not create separate databases or tables for what are 'identical' structures.  There may be enough differences between the translations to justify separate tables.  Before answering that, please further describe the differences, and what queries you expect to hit the table(s) with.

It feels like one row per verse is desired.  Having a `FULLTEXT` index is probably beneficial.

As for the "relations", first decide whether they are "1:many" or "many:many".  For "many:many", as in "Angel" is a "tag" (not "label") for many verses, and a verse can have multiple tags, have a *separate* table relating the tag and the verse.  It would have (it seems) 3 columns:  tag, chapter, verse, with `PRIMARY KEY(tag, chapter, verse)` and `INDEX(chapter, verse, tag)`.

As for symmetric relations, I usually like to have one row, with the two entries in a canonical form.  The first column would have the "smaller" value.  And any tests would sort the values before testing.  That gets a little tricky when relating compounds like 2-2 and 10-10.  (If you need help with that, suggest you start another Question about a symmetric relation where each key involves a pair numbers.)

(added) In your example table, you have verse 1 relating to verses 85, 116, and 985.  Because of the symmetric relationship, that means that verse 85 is related to verse 1 (and possibly others).  The issue I am bring up is to store only 1:85, and not 85:1.  1 is less than 85 - this controls which of the two possible rows to keep.

One can argue that it might be simpler to have twice as many rows (1:85 *and* 85:1).  I don't have a strong argument for one approach versus the other.

As databases go, the entire dataset, even involving multiple translations, will be "small".  There won't be any scaling problems, but there may be some indexing issues you need to learn about for performance.

If you will be translating into multiple languages, be sure to use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` so that even Chinese can be handled.  I estimate that each translation (in whatever language) will be only a few megabytes.

Chapter number (if numeric) should be `TINYINT UNSIGNED`; verse number should be `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`.  `TEXT` is needed for `verse` (cf Verse 282 of al Baqarah).

Comment: Thank you. Guess I understood most of what you said, except symmetric relations. 1) Are you suggesting that I should have one table and a field for each translation? 2) Can you further elaborate on symmetric relations with a small example please?

Comment: @blackened - I added a couple of paragraphs that may help a little.